# Count how many Radio Buttons are clicked

Tags: jquery

All,
I have the following code to check to see if all of my radio button groups are checked:

```
jQuery("input[type=radio]").click(function(event){
    var num_questions = jQuery("#num_questions").val(),
        new_questions = parseInt(num_questions, 10) + 1,
        radios = jQuery("input[type=radio]"),
        all_answered = true;
    for(var i=1; i<new_questions; i++){
        alert(i);
        var group  = radios.filter('[name=rating_value_'+i+']');
        alert(group.filter(":checked").length);
        if(group.filter(":checked").length==0){
            all_answered = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (all_answered) {
        // a group was found that didn't have an answer selected
        // so do something
        jQuery("#no_answers").html('');
    } 
});
```

This works good to do the check but I have an issue. This code runs before the actual radio button has been marked as clicked so it thinks that there is still one that isn't clicked even if that was the last one. How can I fix this so that it works like I'd liek it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `change` instead of `click`

http://api.jquery.com/change/

This should ensure that it is carried out once the option is actually selected.

*The reason click does not work is that you are performing your checks before the default click event is invoked, the default click event would be the one that selects the actual radio button.*  It seems I may be wrong about this. However change should still work.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills, because I was able to get this to work with click. Here's my code:

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(event) {
    var all_answered = true;
    $('input:radio').each(function() {
        if (!$('input[name="' + $(this).attr("name") + '"]').is(':checked')) {
            all_answered = false;
        }
    });
    alert(all_answered);
});
```

and here's my fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/F8kAH/5/

Comment: Interesting, I must be wrong about the click and the way it selects :/.  Although I have always been told to (and always done myself) use change.  However it does require more work to use click over change.

Comment: Speaking of more work I feel compelled to add that my code above checks the same set of radio buttons for each button in the set. In this case I chose brevity over efficiency. You could change the HTML to group up the radio buttons (div tags for example) then use a selector to select the groups so you only check each group once.